# How to debug my C++ program that calculates CGPA?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to write a simple code in C++ to calculate CGPA. It is a practice code. There is no error in code when I start to build. But it is not running.

I am using codeblocks. I have checked everything. but can not find any problems in it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;


int main()

{
    int g,h,i,a=0, grade[g],hour[h];
    char course[10];

    float z=0,sum =0, result=0, totalhour=0;



    cout<<"How Many Course's do you want to calculate for CGPA:  ";
    cin>> a;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Please Enter your Course name, Credit hour & Grade point of the your course"<<endl;

    for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<". no Course name: ";
        cin>>course[i];
        cout<<"-----";

        cout<<"Credit Hour: ";
        cin>>hour[h];
        cout<<"-----";

        cout<<"Grade point: ";
        cin>>grade[g];
        cout<<"\n";
    }


    for (i=1; i<=a;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<".no Course----";
         z= grade[g]*hour[h];
        cout<<"Grade point X Credit Hour = "<<grade[g]<<" X "<<hour[h]<<" = "<<z<<endl;

       sum = sum+z;
       totalhour= totalhour+hour[h];


    }
        result = sum / totalhour;
        cout<<"Your total Credit hour Completed is : "<<totalhour<<endl;
        cout<<"----Your Total CGPA is --------     = "<<result<<endl;


   getch();
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a sufficiently detailed diagnostic. What is this supposed to do that it's not doing?

Comment: I love abbreviations.  What is "CGPA"?

Comment: "There is no error in my coding". <-- that claim is not going to age well, I think :)

Comment: Right. The very first line of `main()`'s "coding" has a major error, that pretty much wrecks everything out of the starting gate.

Comment: [Rubber Ducky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is wondering "What are the values of `g` and `h` in `int g,h,i,a=0, grade[g],hour[h];`?"

Comment: "There is no error in my coding", then explain, what is the size of the array `grade[g]`, or `hour[h]`?

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will help you walk through your code, step by step, so you can see values of variables.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session, including expected variable values, actual variable values and indicate the statement causing the issue.

Comment: Use all of the compiler diagnostics. My compiler spits out four warnings, all of them telling me what's wrong.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews [cumulative grade point average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grading_in_education)

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Character arrays can overflow.

Comment: BTW, your `course` name array is for 10 *single characters*.  Not 10 strings or texts, but 10 single letters.  Your code can't handle the course name "Introduction to C++", as it will only read the "I".

Comment: Your calculation `z = grade[g] * hour[h];` doesn't change.  The `h` and `g` array indexes don't change inside the loop.  You might as well get rid of the loop, or change it.

Comment: Because the value of `z` doesn't change, you can move the `sum` assignment to before the loop and change to: `sum = z * a;`  Likewise with `totalhour`:  `totalhour = hour[h] * a;`

Comment: BTW, array indices start at 0, not 1.  Your input loop should be: `for (i = 0; i < a; ++i)`

Comment: You probably want hour and grade inputs to be:  `cin >> hour[i]; ` and `cin >> grade[i];`

Comment: You are missing a space in your `#include` statements

Comment: First you say "There is no error in my coding.", then you say "But it is not working.", which contradicts the first statement... So, what is it, is there an error/bug or not? If it doesn't work the answer is obviously "yes". If it works, the answer is "no" (but then why are you asking here?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems in your code:

1. What happens if user input is larger then 10? you assume it will be smaller (you will get undefined behavior since the array size is 10, and your for loop runs until user input)
2. `int g,h,i,a=0, grade[g],hour[h];` - what is the size of grade and hour? you can not "dynamically" give them a size. You must tell what size they are when you declare them, unless you use dynamic containers such as `std::vector`.